# Proof verifiation: $\log_a b$ is either an integer or irrational number

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

My idea is to show that $\log_b a$ cannot be written as a fraction if it is not an integer. Here is what I tried:

Write $\log_b a$ as follows: 
$$\log_b a = \frac{p}{q}$$
Where $p,q$ are in their lowest form. By definition:
$$b^{\frac{p}{q}} = a$$
Raising to the $b$<sup>th</sup> power:
$$b^p = a^q$$
Now, write $b,a$ in their unique prime factorization raising them to $p$ and $q$ then cancel common primes out. If the result is $1=1$ then we are done. Otherwise, by **Euclid Lemma** These two numbers cannot be equal. Hence, there are no integers $p,q$ such that $b^p = a^q$.

---

I want to check my method above.

Comment: $$\log_8 2 = \frac13$$

Comment: What about $\log_{4}(2)$?

Comment: Then, what went wrong in the proof?!

Comment: To find out what went wrong in the proof trace it step by step numerically starting with the numbers that make a counterexample. You should see where your logic fails.

Comment: I think you didn't use the Euclid lemma correctly, though I don't no much about it. But I see that every thing else is correct in the proof, so try to make sure of the use of this lemma... @Majed Saeed

Comment: I think you can prove your statement if $GCD(a,b)=1.$

Comment: Thanks @user376343 for this note.

Comment: I suppose you mean $a$ and $b$ to be positive integers?

Comment: @MPW yes they are.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are trying to prove is false.

For example,

$$\log_4 8 = \frac{3}{2} $$

Comment: Thanks for this counter example.

Comment: What went wrong in the proof?

Comment: "if the result is $1=1$ then we are done" What does that mean?

Comment: There are two integers $p,q$ such that $b^p = a^q$

Comment: I should clarify. What you were writing is a proof by contradiction. You assume something you want to disprove and show that it implies something false. However, when you wrote "if the result is $1=1$, then we are done", you aren't done, because you haven't derived something false.

Answer (score 1):

On the country there are many such logarithms which are rationals. For example $$ log _{4} 2 =1/2$$
In general $$\log_{2^k} 2=1/k$$